# Android MediaPlayer "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: android, sockets, media-player

We are using `MediaPlayer` to stream mp3 music which is first cached to local file and MediaPlayer  is to stream it via localserver. It worked pretty nice (for about 1.5 years on any android > 1.6 devices) till Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 updated to Android 2.3.3. Suddenly and only on that device and with Android 2.3.3 the audio streaming stopped working.

`MediaPlayer` occasionally rises error (100,0) but mostly it just stack on `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` method. 
The investigation shows that issue happens because of

```
“java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer”
```

which points to the line:

```
outstream.write(buffer, skipFirst, length);
```

which by the way is successfully executed 2 times before Exception

The code is quite complex so its hard for me to provide it here, but I can return with more info if needed.

In some reason `MediaPlayer` closes connection just at the moment when we start to fill it with content. Also what seems to be quite strange, from time to time (1/20) `MediaPlayer` succeeds to play music.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your proxy parses the Range HTTP header correctly. Xperia devices send range requests in the form of `Range: bytes=10000-20000` instead of the more common `Range: bytes=10000-`.

I'm not sure if this really is the problem, but it fixed playback on some newer Xperia devices, my guess would be that the MediaPlayer on older devices is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

to be able to assist you more I think we need some code snippets and a debug log. Could you arrange that for us, please. Or even better if you could pass me a version (stripped if you like - I do not wish to steal commersial ideas from you) of the APK and then I could test the apk on our other phones.

Johan, Sony Ericsson Developer support

Comment: @Johan - seeing exactly the same issue - what's the best way to contact you?

Comment: i have been offline for quite some time. Sorry. Try semcabris@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

When you seek or skip or the connection is lost and MediaPlayer keeps reconnecting to the proxy server, you must send this response with Status 206 after you get the request and range(int) from the client.

```
String headers += "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\n";
headers += "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n";
headers += "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
headers += "Content-Length: " + (fileSize-range) + "\r\n";
headers += "Content-Range: bytes "+range + "-" + fileSize + "/*\r\n";
headers += "\r\n";
```

And when you receive a request from MediaPlayer that does not contain Range in the HTTP header , then it is requesting a new stream file, in this case your response header should look like this:

```
String headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
headers += "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n";
headers += "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
headers += "Content-Length: " + fileSize + "\r\n";
headers += "\r\n";
```

Enjoy!